# ocupar Json desde flask hacia un html

Tags: python, flask, leaflet

Tengo un problema a la hora de lograr querer hacer leer el json en un html a traves de flask, la idea es pasar el json desde un codigo de python por medio de post, este es el código mencionado, acorte un poco de codigo arriba, que son las conexiones a la base de datos y creación de la misma.

```
def datos_base(con, id):
    i = 0
    cursor_base = con.cursor()
    cursor_base.execute('SELECT  lat,lon FROM rutas WHERE id=? order by fecha,hora',(id,))
    data = cursor_base.fetchall()
    lat = []
    lon = []
    for row in data:
        lat.append((row[0]))
        lon.append(row[1])
        gps['data'].append({"lat":lat[i],"lon":lon[i]})
        i = i+1

con = sql_conexion()

gps = {'data':[]}

datos = pd.read_csv(r'rutas.csv')
datos.to_sql('rutas', con, if_exists='replace', index= False)


datos_base(con,"10")

datos_json = json.dumps(gps)
with open('datos.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(datos_json, json_file)
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/json-example','datos.json')
```

Después tengo lo de la app.py, que es lo de flask, que aquí ya vienen mis problemas porque no logro hacer que mi html reproduzca los datos llegados.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/json-example', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def json_example():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['archivo']
        return render_template('clase.html', points=json.dumps(f))
    return render_template('clase.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Código de mi html(clase.html)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang=es>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
   <style>
     #map {position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;}
   </style>
</head>



 <body>
  <div id= "map">
    <script>
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0],1)
    
      L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=9cvF9Sx9VZvSGxVJ6Xnw',{
        attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
      }).addTo(map);

      var points = JSON.parse('{{points}}');
      var marker;

      for (var i = 0; i < points.lenght; i++){
        marker = L.marker([points[i].lat,points[i].lon]).addTo(map)

      }
    </script>


  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Como explique antes, mi idea es enviar por método post el json desde el primer archivo.py, al servidor de flask, para que flask me lo redirija a mi html y este muestre todos los datos del json, el json contiene valores de latitudes y longitudes, para poder mostrarlas en el mapa con leaflet, pero no logro hacer que flask me envié el json o ocuparlo, agradecería mucho la ayuda y aclaraciones de mis errores y perdón si es mucho código, pero sentía que todo era importante para entender.

Comment: si sabes que estas enviando el string `datos.json` y no un json??

Comment: debes de colocar el parámetro `json` e indicar la variable que contiene el json por ejemplo `request.post("url", json=datos_json)`

Comment: @Christian hola al final era y no era el problema, en si no envía el json, pero si lo recibía en flask, el caso es que dándome cuenta,  el archivo que envía el json por método post recibe al respuesta de flask, sine embargo la pagina web no muestra ningún cambio, mi duda es, actualizo esta pregunta, creo una nueva o como, llevo estos 3 días buscando y no se en que fallo :/

Comment: debes de actualizar la  pregunta. Lastimosamente no soy experto en Flask y no sé más de lo que te dije :c

Comment: dale igual muchas gracias por esa ayuda, se agradece <3